# How to calculate the point(x2,y2) with the point (x1,y1) and the angle

Tags: c#

Again i came back with a question.

1.I have a line drawing from a point (x2,y2) for which i do no the end point(Say point unknown as in the fig),but i knew the line length and the angle from the vector (x2,y2). Can any one help me how to calculate the unknown points.

[image]

Thanks,
Lokesh.

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: I have tried the solution posted in the below thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536428/draw-a-line-at-a-specific-angle-in-java
Here they dint bother about the diagonal line,but in my above query i need to calculate the point based on my diagonal line length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This* looks like a job for ... *[Trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry)-man*.

Consider the following diagram:

```
          /|
         /B|
        /  |
       /   |
      /    |
   c /     | a
    /      |
   /       |
  /       _|
 /A      |C|
*----------+
      b
```

You know the angle `B`, it's 45<sup>o</sup>. You also know `C` is 90<sup>o</sup> because that's the "right angle" bit of the right angle triangle.

And, because the angles inside a triangle add up to 180<sup>o</sup>, angle `A` must also be 45<sup>o</sup>.

You also know the length of the hypotenuse `c`. With trigonometry<sup>(a)</sup>, you can get the lengths of the other two sides with:

```
a = c sin A
b = c cos B
```

Then simply add those to your starting point (making sure you get the signs right) and you have your ending point.

For example, let's say your hypotenuse was `1.414213562`, a number I just just picked at random off the top of my head :-)

The length `a` is `c sin A` or `1.414213562 * sin 45`, which is `1.414213562 * 0.707106781` or `1`.

Wow, what were the chances of that? :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> My children reminded me of the "soh cah toa" (pronounced so car toe ah) rule, where "opposite" and "adjacent" sides are location from the angle `X`:

```
soh : sin X = opposite / hypotenuse
cah : cos X = adjacent / hypotenuse
toa : tan X = opposite / adjacent

          /|
         / |
        /  |
       /   |
      /    |
 hyp /     | opp
    /      |
   /       |
  /       _|
 /X      | |
*----------+
     adj
```