# Get the coordinates at the edge of the screen from a given angle

Tags: java, math, coordinates

I know the startpoint (the middle of the screen) and the angle (in my example 20°). Now I want to know the position on the edge of the screen, like an invisible line is drawn from the center to the edge in the given angle. For better explanation, I included an image:

[image: example]

Comment: I guess you just need to know the size of the screen, don't you (as well as the absolute coordinates of your known point) ?

Comment: I can get the height and the width with `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`, so y of my known point is `height / 2` and x is `width / 2`.

Comment: The unknown point is at x = 0, determining y is just a matter of geometry using the angle. Is this geometry problem your question ?

Comment: If my angle is, let's say 130°, how do I know whether x or y should be 0?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536428/draw-a-line-at-a-specific-angle-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to calculate a point on a circle with a radius equal to or greater than the maximum diagonal, and then just clip it to the screen boundary.

Using Pythagoras' theorem, the length of the maximum diagonal will be

```
float d = Math.sqrt((width/2)*(width/2) + (height/2)*(height/2));
```

So you can calculate the point on the circle like this (angle is in radians clockwise from the top):

```
float x = Math.sin(angle) * d;
float y = -Math.cos(angle) * d;
```

Then you have to clip the vector from the origin to the point to each of the 4 sides, e.g for the right and left sides:

```
if(x > width/2)
{
    float clipFraction = (width/2) / x; // amount to shorten the vector
    x *= clipFraction;
    y *= clipFraction;
}
else if(x < -width/2)
{
    float clipFraction = (-width/2) / x; // amount to shorten the vector
    x *= clipFraction;
    y *= clipFraction;
}
```

Also do this for height/2 and -height/2. Then finally you can add width/2, height/2 to x and y to get the final position (with the center of the screen being width/2, height/2 not 0,0):

```
x += width/2
y += height/2
```

Comment: I guess this also explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536428/draw-a-line-at-a-specific-angle-in-java

Comment: I tried it, but I think I did something wrong because it isn't working. I pasted my code into the question.

Comment: You just need to check that your minus signs and comparison operators are correct. I've edited my answer to show clipping for -width/2

Comment: Are you using degrees or radians for the angle? You can convert to radians with Math.toRadians(angle). Also use sin for x and -cos for y to go clockwise from the top