# Draw a Line in Java using length not coordinates

Tags: java, recursion, lines

I'm trying to make a program that draws a Koch fractal. Is there any way I can draw a line in Java by length instead of coordinates?

A koch fractal looks kind of like a snowflake. The repeating pattern is equilateral triangles inserted 1/3 of the way into each line (with the triangle's sides being 1/3 the length of the line). 
[image]

Originally I was trying to draw triangles recursively, but I couldn't figure out how to calculate the coordinates. Then I thought it would be way easier if I could just draw lines of a certain length and rotate them, and reduce the length of the lines each time. Except that I don't know if I even can draw lines by length in Java. I have tried searching the internet for this and have not found an answer, which makes me think it's not possible, but I thought I would ask here just to make sure.

I realize this is way beyond my technical college level. I also realize I could probably find a complete program that someone else has already written, but I want to see if I can figure it out (mostly) on my own.

Comment: Which drawing/painting API?

Comment: What did you search for? Did you look at the related questions when you posted this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw a line at a specific angle in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536428/draw-a-line-at-a-specific-angle-in-java)

Comment: I did read that question but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my problem. @sparky thanks for editing this, it is my first question here and my natural tendency is to over-inform

Comment: Hi Jacqueline, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the person who answered and to yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming that you have some sort of function `drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)` in whatever API you are using for Java. If this is true, and you want to draw a line by length I would believe you could just do it using the standard trigonometry functions (`Math.sin(...)`, `Math.cos(...)` and `Math.tan(...)`).

**Example**

What you would want to draw using a given length is at least the following data:

- A starting coordinate
- The angle of the line with the line y = c (where c is any number)
- The length of the line

Your code could then use something like this:

```
public void drawLineByLength(int xStart, int yStart, double angle, double length) {
    int xEnd = (int) (xStart + (Math.cos(angle) * length));
    int yEnd = (int) (yStart + (Math.sin(angle) * length));

    drawLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
}
```

Note that you will have to import the Math class for this method. In addition, it will only work if you were to have a `drawLine(...)` function available to you that takes the coordinates of two points.

**Implementation**

If I understand your intentions, you would want to keep track of the current coordinate the "pen" is at; the angle it is drawing at; and the length of the next line it is going to draw. You could add something at the end of the `drawLineByLength(...)` method that updates these variables.

Comment: I am using drawLine with 4 coordinates. The thing that threw me off is, my understanding is that the program will completely re-draw the whole line every time it increases a level of complexity. It's easy to draw this design by hand just adding more triangles, but when I started thinking about redrawing the whole thing every time using coordinates, it seemed impossible to figure out the new coordinates. I guess I need to refresh my trig skills.