# How to find anchor/rotation point in Java?

Tags: java, swing, trigonometry

Ok I've been trying to rotate a Rectangle that sits on top of an image.  I have a Scrollable class that displays the Image.  I can draw Rectangles on top of the Image.  My problem is trying to rotate the Rectangles when the Image is rotated.  The Rectangle gets lost and placed in the wrong location.

I've already tried suing Graphics2D, AffineTransform, createTransformedShape() but no luck.

What I'm trying to do now is to rotate the Rectangle manually.  I'm trying to get the Rectangle Point(x,y) using below formula:

```
double rectX = (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) * (x - anchorX) - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) * (y - anchorY)) + anchorY;

double rectY = (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) * (x - anchorX) - Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) * (y - anchorY)) + anchorY;
```

How can I find the anchorX and anchorY values using Java?  I've tried diving the Image height by 2 but doesn't work for all rotation angles.  Do I have to get the JPanel width and height or something?  Is there a formula that Java uses to find anchor points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the goal, but I see two possible alternative approaches:

- Use an inverse transform, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244285).
- Render the upright image and rectangle(s) into a [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and rotate the composite image, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288714).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make it like a a box rolling across the top, you have to find the bottom corner in direction of travel. If you're rolling to the right, you need the bottom right corner.