# obtain a new rotated imageIcon from another one?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, imageicon

my problem is very simple:

I've got an ImageIcon, and i want to obtain another one that is rotated exactly rotation*90° times. This is the method:

```
private ImageIcon setRotation(ImageIcon icon, int rotation);
```

I would prefer not having to use an external class.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate JLabel or ImageIcon on Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287499/rotate-jlabel-or-imageicon-on-java-swing)

Answer (score 2):

## Get BufferedImage from ImageIcon

All transformations to images are usually done to the [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). You can get Image from [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) and then convert it to BufferedImage:

```
Image image = icon.getImage();
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
    image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics bg = bi.getGraphics();
bg.drawImage(im, 0, 0, null);
bg.dispose();
```

## Rotate

Then you can rotate it -90 to 90 degrees using following code:

```
public BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage bi, float angle) {
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), bi.getWidth() / 2.0, bi.getHeight() / 2.0);
    at.preConcatenate(findTranslation(at, bi, angle));

    BufferedImageOp op = 
        new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
    return op.filter(bi, null);
}

private AffineTransform findTranslation(
                        AffineTransform at, BufferedImage bi, float angle) {
    Point2D p2din = null, p2dout = null;

    if (angle > 0 && angle <= 90) {
        p2din = new Point2D.Double(0, 0);
    } else if (angle < 0 && angle >= -90) {
        p2din = new Point2D.Double(bi.getWidth(), 0);
    }
    p2dout = at.transform(p2din, null);
    double ytrans = p2dout.getY();

    if (angle > 0 && angle <= 90) {
        p2din = new Point2D.Double(0, bi.getHeight());
    } else if (angle < 0 && angle >= -90) {
        p2din = new Point2D.Double(0, 0);
    }
    p2dout = at.transform(p2din, null);
    double xtrans = p2dout.getX();

    AffineTransform tat = new AffineTransform();
    tat.translate(-xtrans, -ytrans);
    return tat;
}
```

This works great rotating image from -90 up to 90 degrees, it does not support more than that. You can run through [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) documentation for more explanation on working with the coordinates.

## Set BufferedImage to ImageIcon

Finally you populate ImageIcon with transformed Image: `icon.setImage((Image) bi);`.