# Java Rotate ImageIcon About Center by Given Angle

Tags: java, image, swing, rotation, imageicon

This seems like an easy task, but I've literally searched for hours and haven't found anything so far. I have an ImageIcon which I would like to rotate by a certain angle.

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Edit: I tried converting the ImageIcon to a BufferedImage, and rotating the Graphics2`bPlayerImage = new BufferedImage(
                playerSize, playerSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

```
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bPlayerImage.getGraphics();
    g.rotate(Math.toRadians(turnAngle));
    g.drawImage(playerImage, x, y, null);`
```

The image doesn't appear to rotate.

Comment: See [Rotate JLabel or ImageIcon on Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287499/rotate-jlabel-or-imageicon-on-java-swing)

Comment: `" I've literally searched for hours and haven't found anything so far..."` -- I suggest that you keep on searching. Image rotation is a pretty common question here. I'll bet with a little more searching you'll find much useful information and code examples.

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420651/230513).

Comment: _suggest that you keep on searching._ or post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)