# Drawing paint over a buffered image?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Hi guys I know this is a common one, but i've searched around quite a bit and can't seem to get my paint method to draw over the components in my JPanel.

My paint method is linked to a button press. It prints out about 1500 data points and their assigned cluster (kmeans)

```
 package eye_pathscanner;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ReplayData extends JPanel {

// replay type can be parsed as argument into draw() to change paints behaviour
private int ReplayType = 0;

public ArrayList<DataPoint> points;

//Initialise records
public ReplayData()
{
    points = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
}

public void ReplaceData() {
    points = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
}

public void PrintPoints()
{

}
public void addPoint(DataPoint point) {
    points.add(point);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    Random random = new Random();
    final float luminance = 0.9f;

    if (ReplayType == 1)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (int x = 0; x < kMeans.NUM_CLUSTERS; x++)
        {
            // Saturation ideal between 0.1 and 0.3
            float saturation = (random.nextInt(2000) + 1000) / 10000f;
            float hue = random.nextFloat();
            Color cluster_colour = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, luminance);

            // Randomise the border colour
            saturation = (random.nextInt(2000) + 1000) / 10000f;
            hue = random.nextFloat();
            Color cluster_colour_border = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, luminance);

            double centroidx = kMeans.centroids.get(x).getmX();
            double centroidy = kMeans.centroids.get(x).getmY();

            for (int i = 0; i < kMeans.TOTAL_DATA; i++) 
                if(kMeans.dataSet.get(i).cluster() == x){
                    // Set each child data point to a colour so you can see which cluster it belongs too
                    g.setColor(cluster_colour);
                    g.fillRect((int)TrackerData.getRecordNumber(i).getEyeX(),(int)TrackerData.getRecordNumber(i).getEyeY(), 3, 3);
                    g.drawLine((int)kMeans.dataSet.get(i).X(),(int)kMeans.dataSet.get(i).Y(), (int)centroidx, (int)centroidy);
                    //g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.setColor(cluster_colour_border);
                    g.drawRect((int)TrackerData.getRecordNumber(i).getEyeX(),(int)TrackerData.getRecordNumber(i).getEyeY(), 3, 3);
                }

            g.setColor(black);
            g.fillOval((int)centroidx,(int)centroidy, 15, 15);


        }
    }


}

// 1 for K-means with different colour cluster groups
// 2 for slow replay

public void draw(int i) {
    ReplayType = i;
    repaint();
}
```

}

This code all works great for me, however I lose the image that was drawn beneath the paint after using it. I can maximize the page and the image shows up again but over the paint? (can anyone explain this behavior).

```
    JLabel picture_panel = new JLabel();
    picture_panel.setBounds(70, 130, 640, 797);
    picture_panel.addMouseListener(this);   
    BufferedImage img = null;

    try 
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Eyetracker_Images/Random.jpg")); // eventually C:\\ImageTest\\pic2.jpg
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        picture_panel.setIcon(icon);

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Heres where my image is created, and it's called as shown below on one my buttons

```
 replayData.setBounds(0, 0, 802, 977);
 frame.getContentPane().add(replayData); 
 replayData.draw(1);
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe an artifact of using `setBounds()`. Moreover, you appear to be using the default layout manager without invoking `pack()` on the enclosing container.

As you already have a `BufferedImage` containing the rendered image, simply invoke `drawImage()` in your implementation of `paintComponent()`. Examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288714/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25170471/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513).

Also consider overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of `ReplayData`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288714/230513), to establish its dimensions.