# drawing a shape over an image and rotating it in java

Tags: java, graphics

Hi I am drawing a shape over an image. The shape basically contains a couple of connected lines. I now need to rotate the drawn shape but not the background image. The code that i have so far is:

```
public void drawTrack(){
    try {

        File input = new File(mapPath);
        md.image = ImageIO.read(input);
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        System.out.println("Error:"+ie.getMessage());
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = md.image.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    BasicStroke bs = new BasicStroke(2);
    g2d.setStroke(bs);


    int currentX = Integer.parseInt(ts.xcord.getText());
    int currentY = Integer.parseInt(ts.ycord.getText());
    int scale = Integer.parseInt(ts.size.getText());
    td.computeTracksMotion(currentX, currentY, scale);

    for(TracksMotion currentTm: td.tm){
    // drawing the lines    g2d.drawLine(currentTm.oldX,currentTm.oldY,currentTm.newX,currentTm.newY);
    }

    md.repaint();
}
```

Could you let me know what I should do.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You could explore the [Java2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/TOC.html) API and use the translate and rotate methods from Graphics2D.

An example you find [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/TransformTranslationandRotation.htm).

```
  AffineTransform rat = new AffineTransform();
  rat.setToTranslation(100, 0);
  rat.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
  g2.transform(rat);
```

Please note that the angle is provided in radians.

Comment: when I use g2d.rotate for some reason my image is not rotating.

Comment: @Tom did you check the example, and did you make sure that it was repainted?

Comment: I'm afraid this will have the effect of rotating the entire graphics context, as shown in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420651

Answer (score 1):

One way to rotate a [`Shape`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) without affecting the background is to use the `createTransformedShape()` method of [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html), as seen in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon).