# Shape properties from an Image in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have an Image and I'm able to draw a rectangle on the image like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
graphics2D.draw(rect);
```

Then I rotate the Image and the drawn rectangle also rotates as expected.  But now how can I get a reference to the newly rotated Rectangle?  I need the properties of the rotated Rectangle like Point, width, height....

I don's see that Graphics2D has a method like getShape()?  Also, the rectangle passed to the Graphics2D when calling its draw(Rectangle) method doesn't change.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the code you are using to rotate the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [AffineTransform](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) class.

```
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.rotate(Math.PI/2);
Shape transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(shape);
```

But it would yield you only the shape, which you can use for drawing. If you need exact points of rotated rectangle, you'll need to transform each point separately:

```
transform.transform(point_before, point_after);
```