# A class in Swing or AWT Library that has flexible size

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm looking for a class in `javax.swing` or `java.awt` that gives flexible size to the object. Say that we name this class `MyClass`. When I add `MyClass` to `MyPanel`, it will be shaped with the objects that lie within it. To be more specific, if I draw a Rectangle, MyClass's size will be that of rectangle's, if I draw a circle, `MyClass's` size will be that of circle's, etc.

So far I've seen some classes but all are rectangular in shape: `Container, Canvas, JLayeredPane`, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a suitable layout, any class that implements the [`Shape`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface is a good candidate. You can use the `createTransformedShape()` method of [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) to transform it, as seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593066/rotating-a-shape-vertically-around-the-x-axis/5594424#5594424).

Comment: This sounds great. I am planning to put a line+string in this thing. It should be simpler, eh? Do you think I need AffineTransform and matrix algebra?

Comment: in generally for nicest and seftsold GUI and 2D/3D painting you have to buil-in top-level artist feel, sence make think better, nicest and s*e*x*y as other :-), excelent algebra is good base for that, both +1

Comment: `AffineTransform` hides most of the algebra; but remember, "rotation and translation are not commutative!"—[Geometric Transformations](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use another JPanel, but the key is in what layout managers that the containers (perhaps another JPanel) use and how the components are placed into the containers -- with what constraints, if any.  For more on this, please read the tutorials on how to use the various more user-friendly layout managers: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Now as to your second issue, that of drawing shapes, you'll have to give more information to solve it. Are the curves allowed limitless? Or are just rectangles and ovals allowed?

Comment: Simply, my object will compose of a line (its constraints can dynamically change with MouseEvents) and a string.

Answer (score 1):

by follows [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) tutorial I can image that by creating un-decorated fully translucent [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) / [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), my favorite would be just [JWindow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) which is un-decorated by default(heavens this `Container` lost from `Swing tutorial`!, or am I blind???)

to this fully translucent you have to add parent [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) or better would be [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). There you should adds any of possible sharpes

I think that you can pretty to forgot for usage of `AWT Component`s, all possible start with `"J" == Swing JComponents`