# How to move pictures in a radial movement?

Tags: java, object, 3d, rotation

I'm trying to build a food menu that the first things users will see on the screen monitor are rotating images of twelve different dishes. I imagine trying to use threads and a  timer that will rotate the objects in a circle via changing coordinates or layout managers.

However, 3d rotational movements are encouraged to which I have no real experience in. I've also heard that you can use a java applet and let javascript rotate the objects. I welcome any recommendations and thank you for reading.

Comment: *"use a java applet and let javascript rotate the objects"* Terrible idea.  1) It could be done all in JS (easier with the help of an HTML5 canvas), or it could all be done in Java.  No need to mix the two. 2) Why an applet?  What does the browser window wrapper do for it?

Comment: lol thanks I concur, I have not moved to JS and Front End in general thank you again for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go the whole [Java 3D](http://java3d.java.net/) or [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL) route, you can get a 2½ D effect by using `AffineTransform` and varying *x*, *y* and the apparent size. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513).

Comment: thank you again for the answer and I've been playing around more with WebGl and OpenGL now, but ill definitely take a look