# Swing (AWT) recognizing drawn shape

Tags: java, swing, awt

Hello I'm not an expert neither in Java nor Swing but I was thinking (I don't want solution, maybe tutorial or idea) is it possible (and if it is) how to recognize shape drawn in window and make it 3d by rotating it about axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recognizing shapes is not a trivial exercise, but [Java2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) easily accommodates rotating defined instances of classes implementing the [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface in two dimensions. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513) illustrates a few transformations. [`Java3D`](http://java3d.java.net/) and [Java OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL) are three dimensional alternatives.