# Rotating Image (getting it back to original position)

Tags: java, image, swing, rotation, paintcomponent

Using "Affine Transformation" I can rotate `imageA` easily. As well, `imageA` will move along with `imageB`.  However, I cannot seem to find a way to move `imageA` back to its original position after I have rotated it.

(I have done some research on some sites and apparently the best method is to move the image back to its original position so that it looks like its rotating from an anchor point.)

Heres my code so far:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;


    af.translate(imageBx, imageBy); // moves ImageA to imageb's position
    af.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), imageB.getHeight(this) / 2, imageB.getWidth(this) / 2);


    g2d.drawImage(imageA, af, null);
    g2d.drawImage(imageB, imageBx, imageBy, null);
  }
```

If anyone can help me move `imageA` back to its original position (which is right on `imageB`) that would extremely helpful!

Comment: See if this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420651/230513) helps.

Comment: I looked that over but the code rotates the entire panel, I just want to rotate 1 Image (that is connected to another; similiar to a tank and its arm) on a fixed rotate point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I looked that over, but the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420651/230513) rotates the entire panel; I just want to rotate one `Image` on a fixed rotate point.

Two things may help guide your understanding:

- The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420651/230513) cited uses `rotate(double theta)`; it is *preceeded* by a translation to the origin and *succeeded* by a translation the panel's center. Note that the operations are performed in the *apparent* reverse of the declared order. Your example (may have meant to) invoke `rotate(double theta, double anchorx, double anchory)`. The two effect the same result, the latter being a convenient alternative to the former.
- This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513) contrasts how one can transform the graphics context (g2d) or the image itself. Your example invokes `drawImage(Image img, AffineTransform xform, ImageObserver obs)`, which concatenates `xform` to the existing graphics transform; this affects all subsequent drawing. It may be easier to keep them separate.