# Rotating image on the center of jpanel

Tags: java, swing

How to rotate image on it's center pivot and on the center of a jpanel ? I've tried to use this code, but the image only rotate on its center pivot on the top left of jpanel, but not on the center of the jpanel. Any help would be appreciated

```
public class aboutPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

Image img= new ImageIcon("ball.png").getImage();
Image ball[]=new Image[4];//result of cropping image
AffineTransform afft=new AffineTransform();
int degree=10;

public aboutPanel() {
    initComponents();
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)//crop image to 4 ball
    {
        ball[i]=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new FilteredImageSource(img.getSource(),new CropImageFilter(0,i*78,80,78)));
    }
    if(thr.isAlive()==false)
    {
        thr.start();//start thread
    }

}

Thread thr= new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(aboutPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
});

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); 
    Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
    afft.rotate(Math.toRadians(degree),ball[0].getWidth(this)/2,ball[0].getHeight(this)/2);
    g2d.setTransform(afft);
    g2d.drawImage(ball[0],0,0,this);         
    if(degree==360)
    {
        degree=0;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g2d.drawImage(ball[0],0,0,this);
```

You are drawing the image at location (0, 0);

If you want it in the center then you need to calculate the center. For example the width center would be something like:

```
int widthCenter = (getWidth() - ball[0].getWidth(this)) / 2;
```

Comment: A related approach is outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13031824/230513).

Comment: thanks, but now the ball is revolving around the 0,0 coordinate of the panel

Comment: ohh, the rotate method should be like this afft.rotate(Math.toRadians(degree),getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2);
My problem is solved...thx