# Paint inverse curve using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, shapes

Whilst I'm familiar with overriding Swing's paintComponent(Graphics g) method and drawing custom shapes, I'd struggling to paint a rectangle with some inverse curves (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc7iT.jpg).

Does anyone know how I'd go about creating the Shape object that'll let me paint this?

Comment: It's a cheap workaround but I think your best chance would be to just draw an image you made in some paint program.

Comment: Maybe look into using lines, and than allowing curving of the line via click and drag, or if you made your own shape class with `draw(Graphics2D g2d,int x,int y)` method which would than draw that shape using lines at given point on graphics object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [GeneralPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) is a typical way of describing an arbitrary shape.

In your case, it looks like you will have two lines described with `lineTo` and two (the curves) descibed with `quadTo`, then call closePath() to represent a closed polygon, something like (just picking convenient coordinates here, you'll probably want something a good deal larger):

```
GeneralPath polygon = 
    new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, 4);
polygon.moveTo(2.0, 1.0);
polygon.lineTo(2.0, 5.0);
polygon.quadTo(1.25, 4.75, 1.0, 4.0);
polygon.lineTo(1.0, 2.0);
polygon.quadTo(1.75, 1.75, 2.0, 1.0);
polygon.closePath();
g.draw(polygon);
```

Also, check out this [tutorial on GeneralPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html)

Comment: +1 very nice answer, read about it once or twice and completely forgot it too :P

Comment: You can also transform a `Shape`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513).