# Rotate Vertical direction of JLabel Text

Tags: java, swing

I tried rotating `JLabel` text on based selected angles 30, 90 etc.I wrote `CustomJLabel` class:

```
public CustomJLabel extends JLabel {

    private int angle=360; //setter and getters

    @Override 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {   
        super.paintComponent(g);   
        Rectangle rectangle = g2d.getClipBounds(); 
        g2d.rotate((getAngle() * java.lang.Math.PI) / 4, rectangle.getCenterX(), rectangle.getCenterY());   
    } 
}
```

Main.java:

```
CustomJLabel cst=new CustomJLabel ();
cst.setAngle(value);
cst.repaint();
cst.setSize(getPrefferedsize());
```

When running above code. Its rotated the text correct based on angle. But its not correctly the rectangle shape. Please check the below images.

Horizontal (360)

[image: Horiztal(360)]

Vertical (90)

[image]

[image]

Please observe Red Color Circles and the image was Vertical 90 degress and check the. Here is the missing top and bottom lines for `JLabel`. Why is it missing?

Comment: There isn't enough code available for use to replicate your problem.  Can you provide a runnable example?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Recall that [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) specifies the following:

> Operations that draw the outline of a figure operate by traversing an infinitely thin path between pixels with a pixel-sized pen that hangs *down and to the right* <sup>*</sup> of the anchor point on the path.

When you draw a `Rectangle` having the dimensions returned by `getClipBounds()` using the identity transform, it will be clipped on the right and bottom. When you draw the same `Rectangle` using a different transform, the result will be clipped in a way that depends, in part, on rounding error.

<sup>* emphasis added.</sup>

Comment: That means before rotate text, can i use AffineTransform?

Comment: I don't understand; clipping occurs _after_ any transform is applied. This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513) compares two approaches.