# Drawing squares within squares

Tags: java, swing, graphics, polygon, paintcomponent

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to draw squares within squares and end up with something like this:

[image: Squares]

I've been trying different ways to solve this, but with my limited programming knowledge I can't seem to come up with a simple way to do it. What I wanted to do was make a Polygon to draw a square like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    int x1 = 50;
    int y1 = 50;
    int x2 = 250;
    int y2 = 50;
    int x3 = 250;
    int y3 = 250;
    int x4 = 50;
    int y4 = 250;
    int xPoints[] = {x1,x2,x3,x4};
    int yPoints[] = {y1,y2,y3,y4};
    int nPoints = 4;
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);

}
```

and then simply add a few pixels to the correct point coordinates to move the square. The problem was that I wasn't able to find the y-coordinates along the lines to make the square start further and further towards the centre (sorry, that might be a horrible explanation). Anyhow, I am now stuck and if anyone have a better way to solve this (or could point me in the right direction) that would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you could accomplish this with a simple AffineTranformation, scale and rotate in one go...

Answer (score 5):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594424), you can rotate and scale any `Shape`, such as `Rectangle`. As a practical matter, it may be easier to create a `List<Shape>` and then display some or all of it in `paintComponent()`. For a nice effect, use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to pace the animation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. By the way, it's not supposed to be an animation.

Comment: Ah, animation is optional. Is recursion required?

Comment: Not required, but my professor has been talking about recursion in pretty much every lecture, so it's probably the way to go.