# Java: Rotate Rectangle

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to rotate a Rectangle from the vertices closest to the origin, but it is placing it way off the frame.

I have the following class:

```
class MyRectangle {

    MyRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h, int a){
         xPos = x;
         yPos = y;
         width = w;
         height = h;
         angle = a;
    }

    public int xPos;
    public int yPos;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int angle;


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(angle, rect2.getX() + rect2.width/2, rect2.getY() + rect2.height/2);
        AffineTransform old = gg.getTransform();
        gg.transform(transform);
        gg.rotate(Math.toDegrees(-angle));
        gg.draw(rect2);
    }
}
```

I am caling the rectangle with:

```
MyRectangle rect = new MyRectangle(10, 200, 30, 50, 70);
```

It is showing up like this:
[image]

I included the original un-rotated rectangle. It should rotate from the bottom left vertex.

Comment: The angle of rotation is measured in radians so 70 degrees is 1.22173 radians

Comment: Are you trying to rotate around a corner? So that when the rect is rotated, it is still touching itself?

Comment: @MichaelPickett Yes, the bottom left corner.

Comment: @MaxZoom Changed it to degrees. Forgot to update it.

Comment: Whenever you `gg.rotate()`, the graphics stay rotated. At least in my experience.

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513) compares two approaches.