# Memory game interactivity

Tags: java, swing, memory, jframe

Hei
What I am trying to achieve is to click on a button and a picture would show up, then I would like to save the ID of that picture and be able to click on another button and check if those two pictures ID are the same. If they are, the program would let me keep playing until all pairs are found(I dont care if the found pairs are deleted or just stay) and if a pair is not found in two clicsk the clicked cards would just reset...
thehandler class itself is just an experiment, I dont think there is anything to salvage from there.
Thanks for the help!

```
package memorygame;

    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class GUI extends JFrame {

        private JButton nupp1, nupp2, nupp3, nupp4; // Kasutajaliidese nupud

        ImageIcon A = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("num1.png"));
        ImageIcon B = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("num2.png"));

        public GUI() {
            setTitle("MEMORY Game"); // Tiitel
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 3, 3));

            nupp1 = new JButton(); // Peab manuaalselt nupud lisama displayle
            nupp1.setName("piltyks");
            add(nupp1);

            nupp2 = new JButton();
            nupp2.setName("piltkaks");
            add(nupp2);

            nupp3 = new JButton();
            nupp3.setName("piltyks");
            add(nupp3);

            nupp4 = new JButton();
            nupp4.setName("piltkaks");
            add(nupp4);

            thehandler handler = new thehandler();
            nupp1.addActionListener(handler);
            nupp2.addActionListener(handler);
            nupp3.addActionListener(handler);
            nupp4.addActionListener(handler);

        }

        private class thehandler implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                boolean v22rtusnupp1 = true;
                boolean v22rtusnupp2 = true;
                boolean v22rtusnupp3 = true;
                boolean v22rtusnupp4 = true;

                String v22rtus1 = null;
                String v22rtus2 = null;
                int loendur = 0;
                int tulemus = 0;

                if (event.getSource() == nupp1) {
                    if (v22rtusnupp1 == true) {

                        if (loendur == 0) {
                            v22rtus1 = nupp1.getName();
                        }
                        if (loendur == 1) {
                            v22rtus2 = nupp1.getName();
                        }
                        loendur = loendur + 1;

                        nupp1.setIcon(A);
                        System.out.println(v22rtus1);
                        v22rtusnupp1 = false;
                    }
                }
                if (event.getSource() == nupp2) {
                    if (v22rtusnupp2 == true) {
                        v22rtusnupp2 = false;

                        if (loendur == 0) {
                            v22rtus1 = nupp2.getName();
                        }
                        if (loendur == 1) {
                            v22rtus2 = nupp2.getName();
                        }
                        loendur = loendur + 1;

                        nupp2.setIcon(B);
                        System.out.println(v22rtus1);
                    }
                }
                if (event.getSource() == nupp3) {
                    if (v22rtusnupp3 == true) {
                        v22rtusnupp3 = false;

                        if (loendur == 0) {
                            v22rtus1 = nupp3.getName();
                        }
                        if (loendur == 1) {
                            v22rtus2 = nupp3.getName();
                        }
                        loendur = loendur + 1;

                        nupp3.setIcon(A);
                        System.out.println(v22rtus1);
                    }
                }
                if (event.getSource() == nupp4) {
                    if (v22rtusnupp4 == true) {
                        v22rtusnupp4 = false;

                        if (loendur == 0) {
                            v22rtus1 = nupp4.getName();
                        }
                        if (loendur == 1) {
                            v22rtus2 = nupp4.getName();
                        }
                        loendur = loendur + 1;

                        nupp4.setIcon(B);
                        System.out.println(v22rtus1);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(loendur);

                // if(nupp4.getName() == nupp2.getName()){
                //
                // }
                //
                // if(event.getSource() == nupp1){
                // nupp1.setIcon(A);
                // }else{ if(event.getSource()== nupp3)
                // nupp3.setIcon(A);
                // if(event.getSource()== nupp2)
                // nupp2.setIcon(B);
                // if(event.getSource()== nupp4)
                // nupp4.setIcon(B);
                // }
                //
                //
                //
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your question is missing a question.

Comment: How do I get a button and a picture stored together? How do I give a picture an ID to compare to anotehr picture? When I click on a button which activates a picture which is saved to that button how do I hold it in memory that It could be compared to another? Is my code even salvagable(not like its anything special)? Do I even make sense?

Comment: @user3086917 if we answer all these questions together were actually building your application for you. Do research by yourself, build your application and if you have specific coding problems (errors you cannot find for example) come back and ask

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5735261/230513).