# How to put an image in the background of a window

Tags: java, swing

I'm almost done with my hangman java code. I want to add a picture in the background though.(nightsky.png) How do I do this in the paint graphics method? I created a imageicon in the beginning.

```
public HangmanRevised() {
    setSize(600,400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("nightsky.png");
    Letter = new TextField();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("pick a Letter");
    button = new Button("Enter");
    add(label);
    add(button);
    add(Letter);

    button.addActionListener(this);

    createGame(); 
} 

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 156, Color.green, button);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are painting the image at its actual size, there is no need to do any custom painting.

As has already been suggested you just add the Icon to a JLabel and add the label to your frame (or panel). Then if you want the image to appear at a certion position within the label, then you simply add an EmptyBorder to the label.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the background somewhere, i.e.:

```
//add the following in the HangmanRevised() constructor (?)

button.addActionListener(this);

//To add
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(background.getImage());
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
add(frame); 
//end...

createGame();
```

Comment: can i put this in the public hangmanrevised or should I put it in a different class?

Comment: I haven't seen all your code; but I assume the edited code I put should work in the hangmanrevised...

Comment: I keep getting a compile error saying cannot find symbol for ImagePanel. ANy guesses?

Comment: Put the image in a JLabel and add the label to the panel

Answer (score 0):

By overriding a JPanel, you can redo paintComponent() to paint the image and the JPanel itself should have a paint function for its children (although I haven't tested this functionality).

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("images/background.png").getImage());

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

  private Image img;

  public ImagePanel(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
  }

  public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }

}
```

Comment: any way i can do something like this?

Comment: img = new Image(new ImageIcon("nighsky.png"));

Comment: then in paint graphics method:

Comment: g.drawImage(img, 0, 156, null);  Sorry bout all the post..didnt mean to make them individual

Comment: probably easier just to put the ImageIcon into a JLabel.

Comment: Ok I did this and I have the image now on the screen. But now I need to position it to a certain spot. Can enter cordinates using a type of layout like borderlayout or something?

Comment: This is what i did so far: ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("nighsky.png"), then I did: JLabel label2 = new JLabel(background), then I did: add(label2). But now I need to position it in a precise spot.

Comment: If you absolutely must have it in a specific spot, then use a Null layout `setLayout(null)` and then position it yourself through setLocation, setSize, altho using a null layout is almost always a bad idea. (Altho a game is probably an exception).

Comment: Yea I still can't figure it out. If i can add the image somehow in the graphics paint method then i can do something like g.setImage(image) but this doesnt work

Comment: @Anthony Lagarrigue: You can edit your question to show new code; it'll be easier to read there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also construct any image you like *on-the-fly* using [`2D Graphics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), as suggested in [`RotatableImage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405799/how-to-rotate-an-image-gradually-in-swing/3420651#3420651).