# rotating in java

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

I have a simple question which I cannot find an answer for. In eclipse I have a simple `GRect` and `GOval`. How can I rotate them 90 degrees clockwise?
I have tried `move` and `movePolar` but it doesn't have any effect. Here is the code:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class asd extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run() {
        double x = (getWidth() - FIGURE_WIDTH) / 2;
        double y = (getHeight() - FIGURE_HEIGHT) / 2;
        GRect rect = new GRect(x, y, FIGURE_WIDTH, FIGURE_HEIGHT);
        rect.setFilled(true);
        rect.setColor(Color.RED);
        add(rect);
        GOval oval = new GOval(x, y, FIGURE_WIDTH, FIGURE_HEIGHT);
        oval.setFilled(true);
        oval.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
        add(oval);
}
```

I would like to rotate this 90 degree clockwise.

Comment: Look for a relate question : [Rotate a Java Graphics2D Rectangle?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517688/rotate-a-java-graphics2d-rectangle

Comment: acm API is obsolete and doesn't allow rotate, only move and scale.

Comment: so what should I do .. I didnt get the point.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rotate any object except GPolygon in acm.graphics.  You could easily model the GRect as a GPolygon of course, but I suppose the GOval would have to be approximated by a polygon to use this scheme.

If your rotation is limited, I suppose as a next best course you could create multiple objects in the case of GOval.  For example, if you create ovalH and ovalV, you have the 0, 90, 180 and 270 degree rotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually rotate GObject shapes in the ACM library with the rotate() method. For example:

```
GRect rect1 = new GRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
rect1.setFilled(true);
add(rect1);
rect1.rotate(90);
```

However, the pivot point for this is the top left corner.