# Image is not rotating

Tags: java, swing, image-rotation

[image][image]I am trying to rotate an image, somewhat it works but the problem is that it is not working properly. It's not rotating at exact I want. Image is displaying in some mix formation.

My code on button click :

```
RT90.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                degrees+=90;
                rotateIMG(degrees);
                repaint();
            }
        });
```

rotateIMG() code :

```
public void rotateIMG(double d)
    {
        BufferedImage b ;
        b=a;
        Graphics g;
        g=b.createGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        System.out.println(b.getWidth());
        System.out.println(b.getHeight());

        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(d), b.getWidth()/2, b.getHeight()/2);
        g2d.drawImage(b,0,0,null);

        ImageIcon rtimg = new ImageIcon(b);
        label.setIcon(rtimg);

    }
```

Any idea what's `wrong` in this code?
Here `a` is buffered image which is loaded from image stack and `label` is `JLabel` using to display image.

Comment: Could it be that you display a and b at your panel/frame at the same time?

Comment: "Image is displaying in some mix formation" isn't really clear to me. Could you perhaps provide a screen shot? Of course, an SSCCE would do too.

Comment: There are sometimes problems when trying to paint an image on top of itself. Create a new `BufferedImage` and paint on that instead.

Comment: Check out if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7517766/2581401) can help

Comment: @haraldK - i have put a screen shot. now what the problem is that i don't know. i have put the original image as well as the image displayed after clicking on 90+ degree rotate.

Comment: Yep. The problem is exactly that you're overwriting the image you use as the source.

Comment: @kiheru - overwriting image as source means ? will you tell me where the problem in code ?

Comment: A moment, I'll formulate that as an answer.

Comment: @kiheru I think you nailed it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the image you use as the source (b == a). You need to create a new instead.

```
public void rotateIMG(double d) {
    // Consider also using GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage().
    // I'm just putting here something that should work
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(a.getHeight(), a.getWidth(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = b.createGraphics();

    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(d), a.getWidth()/2, a.getHeight()/2);
    // Note the a instead of b here
    g2d.drawImage(a, 0, 0, null);
    // Do you want to keep the old a or not?
    // a = b;
    ImageIcon rtimg = new ImageIcon(b);
    label.setIcon(rtimg);
}
```

Comment: sir, that code works but the problem is that some portion of image is croped means its not displayed after rotate.

Comment: @user2659972 I just wrote the code, not tried it :-P. The problem may be that since the image dimensions changed the GUI needs to reflect that in the layout. I do not know how your layout works so I can not be sure.

Comment: Another possible source is the translation used in the `rotate()` call. I did not check if it's correct, but copied it from you.

Comment: ok i will try by myself if any problem i face then i will post and thank you for your support.

Comment: The positioning can be a bit complicated. Take a look at the link posted by @camickr.

Comment: yes i am trying that one. if i will made it then i will post you.

Answer (score 2):

> the problem is that some portion of image is cropped

Check out [Rotated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/). It will calculate the correct size of the Icon as it is rotated at various degrees.