# How can I rotate rectangle in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt

My rectangle code:

```
class Rectangle extends JPanel {

 int x = 105;
 int y= 100;
 int width = 50;
 int height = 100;


  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect (x, y, width, height);  
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  }


Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
```

and I have a button "rotate". When the user presses the button with the mouse, the rectangle must rotate 15 degrees.

This is my action code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Object source  = e.getSource();

    if( source == rotate){
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(15), r.getX() + r.getWidth()/2, r.getY() + height/2);
        r.add(transform);
    }
}
```

But the code doesn't work. I don't know why? What do you think?

My edited-action-code part:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object source  = e.getSource();

        if( source == rotate){

            Paint p = new Paint();              
            panel1.add(r);
             repaint();
        }
        }

    class Paint extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.translate(r.getX()+(r.WIDTH/2), r.getY()+(r.HEIGHT/2));
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(15));
        r.equals(g2d);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a Java Graphics2D Rectangle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517688/rotate-a-java-graphics2d-rectangle)

Answer (score 3):

1. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method, not paint(). Don't forget the super.paintComponent() at the start.
2. The `paintComponent()` method is where the painting is done so that is were you need the rotation code. So you could set a variable to indicate if you need to do the rotation or not. So all the `ActionListener` does is set the variable and then invoke repaint().

Or, I've never tried applying a rotation directly to the Rectangle (I've always applied it to the Graphics object in the painting method). Maybe you just need to invoke `repaint()` on the panel in your `ActionListener`. The panel won't know you've changed the Rectangle, so you need to tell it to repaint itself.

Comment: When i do like in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517688/rotate-a-java-graphics2d-rectangle  action part doesnt work. How can i work it?

Comment: @Imogen, I have no idea why your code doesn't work since you didn't post your code. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: yes you right, i am sorry but i dont know how can i put my code in here the comment part :(

Comment: @Imogen, I can't compile or execute that code. You didn't read the `SSCCE` link.