# Rotating a specific graphics object in Java

Tags: java, canvas, rotation

I have a problem in Java. I'm trying to create a 2D shape and rotate it but if I try to rotate it with the `Graphics2D's` rotate method, the whole canvas gets rotated.

I would like to only rotate a specific shape, not the whole canvas.

My current render method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void render(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(super.color);
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(5));
    g2d.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);

}
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a Java Graphics2D Rectangle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517688/rotate-a-java-graphics2d-rectangle)

Comment: Doesn't the post you linked have an answer that points to rotating the whole Graphics2D object itself or am I missing something?

Comment: Look at the second answer, not the accepted one. `create` and `dispose` are your friends

Comment: Nice! Using the Path class helped a lot actually.