# How to rotate the square in my swing app

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, graphics2d, event-dispatching

I have developed a little swing application in which i have drawn a square.Now i want to rotate this square at its center using Thread.The problem i'm having is how to get reference to that square in my rotateSquare() method.
(Actually i need a method,if possible, to rotate the same square instead of wiping out the entire content pane and drawing another rotated square at its position).

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Rotation extends JFrame implements Runnable{
Thread t;
Rotation()
{
    super("Animation of rotation about center");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400,400);

    setContentPane(new Container(){
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
            g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            g2.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
        }
    });

    t=new Thread(this,"pr");
    t.start();


    setVisible(true);
    //setOpacity(0.8f);
}
public void run()
{
    try{
        for(;;)
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){
                rotateSquare();
            }});
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println("Thread interrupted");}
}
public void rotateSquare();
{

}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new Rotation();}});
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- see [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html)
- add parameters [AffineTransform.rotate(intDegrees);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate%28double%29)
- fit rotated Object to the parents bounds [myAffineTransform.translate(getWidth(), getHeight())](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#translate%28double,%20double%29)
- then returns back [Graphics2D#transform(myAffineTransform);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)
- use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `Runnable#Thread` with `Thread.sleep(int)`, that caused freeze or flickering for Graphics2D and locked [EventDispatchThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) untill endless `Thread` ended (never ending in your case)

Comment: can anyone please type a bit of code so that i know exactly what to do as i'm not much experienced with Java 2D Graphics.

Comment: `Timer` is alternative to `Thread`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420651/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You should define a `Square` class that would include code defining a square object. This would have a `draw(Graphics g)` method that would know how to draw the `Square`.

In your other class, you would have a reference to a `Square` object. Under the `paint` method you would call `square.draw(g)`.

This way, you can apply the rotation under the `Square` `draw()` method.