# JUNG animate image along an edge

Tags: java, animation, graph, jung

So I'm using JUNG, which is something new for me. I've already implemented a simple GUI, which displays vertexes and edges and through the use of Transformers I can change shapes and all that. 
But how would I animate an image along an edge?

If the edges were straight lines it'd be easy as I know start and end X and Y coords, but the edges can also be BentLines, CubicCurves or QuadCurves. How would I make, say, a car move along the line that has been drawn?

I've looked at the docs for the PathIterator, but to be honest, I haven't got a clue what it actually does and whether it's apropriate for what I want.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, in fact, is a bit tricky.

First of all, some contortions are necessary in order to obtain the *real* edge shape that is painted on the screen. Fortunately, the relevant code is already contained in the `ShapePickSupport.java` class from JUNG.

Then, one has to compute a point on this shape (which is therefore implicitly assumed to be a line). This involves playing around with the `PathIterator` for computing the total length, and the current position on the line.

I tried to implement this (in a *very* basic and simple form) and encapsulate this in an `ImageAtEdgePainter` class: It receives the `VisualizationViewer` for the edge shape computations, as well as the edge and the image that should be painted. It has a `setImageLocation` method that accepts a value between 0.0 and 1.0, where 0.0 means that the image should be at the start of the edge, and 1.0 means that the image is at the end of the edge, respectively.

Using a dummy graph and a dummy image, the result looks like this:

[image: ImageAtEdge]

where the image oscillates between the end points of the edge. Here is the code, as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.Context;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.Pair;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.Layer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.MultiLayerTransformer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.RenderContext;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;

public class JUNGEdgePathTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static BufferedImage createDummyImage()
    {
        int w = 100;
        int h = 30;
        BufferedImage image = 
            new BufferedImage(w,h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Image", 10, 20);
        g.dispose();
        return image;
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        final Graph<String, String> graph = getGraph();
        final VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv = 
            new VisualizationViewer<String, String>(
                new FRLayout<String, String>(graph));
        final BufferedImage image = createDummyImage();

        String edge = graph.getEdges().iterator().next();
        final ImageAtEdgePainter<String, String> imageAtEdgePainter = 
            new ImageAtEdgePainter<String, String>(vv, edge, image);

        Timer t = new Timer(20, new ActionListener()
        {
            long prevMillis = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (prevMillis == 0)
                {
                    prevMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                long dtMs = System.currentTimeMillis() - prevMillis;
                double dt = dtMs / 1000.0;
                double phase = 0.5 + Math.sin(dt) * 0.5;
                imageAtEdgePainter.setImageLocation(phase);
                vv.repaint();
            }
        });
        t.start();

        vv.addPostRenderPaintable(imageAtEdgePainter);


        f.getContentPane().add(vv);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class ImageAtEdgePainter<V, E> implements VisualizationViewer.Paintable
    {
        private final VisualizationViewer<V, E> vv;
        private final E edge;
        private final BufferedImage image;
        private double imageLocation;

        ImageAtEdgePainter(
            VisualizationViewer<V, E> vv, 
            E edge,
            BufferedImage image)
        {
            this.vv = vv;
            this.edge = edge;
            this.image = image;
        }

        public void setImageLocation(double imageLocation)
        {
            this.imageLocation = imageLocation;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics gr)
        {
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
            Shape shape = getTransformedEdgeShape(vv, vv.getGraphLayout(), edge);
            Point2D p = computePointAt(shape, 0.2, imageLocation);
            //g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            //g.draw(shape);
            //System.out.println(p);
            gr.drawImage(image, (int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY(), null);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean useTransform()
        {
            return true;
        }

    }



    private static double computeLength(Shape shape, double flatness)
    {
        double length = 0;
        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null, flatness);
        double[] coords = new double[6];
        double previous[] = new double[2];
        while (!pi.isDone())
        {
            int segment = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            switch (segment)
            {
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    previous[0] = coords[0];
                    previous[1] = coords[1];
                    break;

                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    double dx = previous[0]-coords[0];
                    double dy = previous[1]-coords[1];
                    length += Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
                    previous[0] = coords[0];
                    previous[1] = coords[1];
                    break;
            }
            pi.next();
        }
        return length;
    }

    public static Point2D computePointAt(
        Shape shape, double flatness, double alpha)
    {
        alpha = Math.min(1.0, Math.max(0.0, alpha));
        double totalLength = computeLength(shape, flatness);
        double targetLength = alpha * totalLength;
        double currentLength = 0;
        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null, flatness);
        double[] coords = new double[6];
        double previous[] = new double[2];
        while (!pi.isDone())
        {
            int segment = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            switch (segment)
            {
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    previous[0] = coords[0];
                    previous[1] = coords[1];
                    break;

                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    double dx = previous[0]-coords[0];
                    double dy = previous[1]-coords[1];
                    double segmentLength = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
                    double nextLength = currentLength + segmentLength;
                    if (nextLength >= targetLength)
                    {
                        double localAlpha = 
                            (currentLength - targetLength) / segmentLength;
                        //System.out.println("current "+currentLength+" target "+targetLength+" seg "+segmentLength);
                        double x = previous[0] + localAlpha * dx;
                        double y = previous[1] + localAlpha * dy;
                        return new Point2D.Double(x,y);
                    }
                    previous[0] = coords[0];
                    previous[1] = coords[1];
                    currentLength = nextLength;
                    break;
            }
            pi.next();
        }
        return null;
    }


    // This method is take from JUNG ShapePickSupport.java
    private static <V, E>  Shape getTransformedEdgeShape(
        VisualizationViewer<V, E> vv, Layout<V, E> layout, E e) {
        Pair<V> pair = layout.getGraph().getEndpoints(e);
        V v1 = pair.getFirst();
        V v2 = pair.getSecond();
        boolean isLoop = v1.equals(v2);
        RenderContext<V, E> rc = vv.getRenderContext();
        MultiLayerTransformer multiLayerTransformer = 
            rc.getMultiLayerTransformer();
        Point2D p1 = multiLayerTransformer.transform(
            Layer.LAYOUT, layout.transform(v1));
        Point2D p2 = multiLayerTransformer.transform(
            Layer.LAYOUT, layout.transform(v2));
        if(p1 == null || p2 == null) 
            return null;
        float x1 = (float) p1.getX();
        float y1 = (float) p1.getY();
        float x2 = (float) p2.getX();
        float y2 = (float) p2.getY();
        AffineTransform xform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
        Shape edgeShape = 
            rc.getEdgeShapeTransformer().transform(
                Context.<Graph<V,E>,E>getInstance(
                    vv.getGraphLayout().getGraph(),e));
        if(isLoop) {
            Shape s2 = rc.getVertexShapeTransformer().transform(v2);
            Rectangle2D s2Bounds = s2.getBounds2D();
            xform.scale(s2Bounds.getWidth(),s2Bounds.getHeight());
            xform.translate(0, -edgeShape.getBounds2D().getHeight()/2);
        } else {
            float dx = x2 - x1;
            float dy = y2 - y1;
            double theta = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
            xform.rotate(theta);
            float dist = (float) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            xform.scale(dist, 1.0f);
        }
        edgeShape = xform.createTransformedShape(edgeShape);
        return edgeShape;
    }


    public static Graph<String, String> getGraph() 
    {
        Graph<String, String> g = new DirectedSparseGraph<String, String>();
        g.addVertex("v0");
        g.addVertex("v1");
        g.addVertex("v2");
        g.addVertex("v3");
        g.addVertex("v4");
        g.addEdge("e0", "v0", "v1");
        g.addEdge("e1", "v1", "v2");
        g.addEdge("e2", "v2", "v3");
        g.addEdge("e3", "v3", "v4");
        g.addEdge("e4", "v4", "v0");
        g.addEdge("e5", "v1", "v3");
        g.addEdge("e6", "v2", "v4");
        return g;
    }
}
```

When you say that you want to move a car along the line, I can imagine that you also want to *align* the image of the car with the edge - that is, to *rotate* the image so that the car always points towards the end of the edge. This would not be sooo difficult. But if this is an issue, you should probably first have a look at other questions (like [Java: Rotate image towards mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607930/java-rotate-image-towards-mouse-position) ) to see whether the answers there can... "inspire" you, or ask it as a separate (not-JUNG-specific) question.

Comment: I hadn't actually considered having to align the car, although now you've mentioned, I feel it's something I would'veprobably realized I needed later on. But thanks anyway ;D
Regarding your answer, it looks quite helpful, but it's late so I've just taken a short look at it. More feedback later asap.

Comment: Works beautifully, exactly what I intended and thanks to you I've now figured out how to work with the PathIterator! Thanks!