# Java Swing Graphics2d rotation jumping

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm writing a simple game for studying purposes. Everything goes fine except one little thing...

I cant figure out how to rotate square without this ugly jumping

[image]

here a simplified version of my program illustrating an issue, here i use one timer, but in original program i have 2 timers one for handle game state and second for repaint:

```
public class soQuestion extends JLabel {

    double r;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g.clearRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.translate(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        g.rotate(r);
        g.translate(-20, -20);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        soQuestion question = new soQuestion();
        frame.add(question);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new javax.swing.Timer(10, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                r += 0.005;
                question.repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

jumping is more visible if rotation delta values is small, for fast rotated objects is less visible..

all rendering hints i used has no effect

PS: Sorry for my english

PPS: i can provide more details if needed, how it looks in full version:

[image]

Comment: You should not be changing state within the paintComponent method but rather within the timer. The paint method should be for painting alone.

Comment: Also, consider creating a collection of images, and then rather than doing complex calculations repeatedly, simply swap images based on the calculations all done at the start.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels in full code i have a two timers one for game state ticks and another for repainting, this simple example only for exampple, if there are important thing for this example i can separate it..

Comment: Did you try with `g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);`?

Comment: @Pshemo thank you sir, its a copy-paste issue...

Comment: What Hovercraft is saying is:  Do not do `g.rotate(r += 0.005);` in a painting method.  Do not alter `r` or any other state variable in a painting method.  It’s actually quite common for painting to be called for many reasons, such as the user moving the mouse over the component.  Also, a single paint operation may consist of *multiple* calls to paintComponent, with different clip regions set by the system.  Change `r` in your Timer’s actionPerformed method instead.

Comment: See also this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420651/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all participants!

It is fully **my mistake and inattention**. I was copied this code section from some source :

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

And before ask a question here i couldn't saw that i used hint related to text rendering.

Special thanks to mr @Pshemo for suggesting of using this rendering hint:

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

I was know about it before asking, but i'm a human and could not figure out where a mistake for an a hour and asked.

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: @trashgod thank you for suggesting answer on my own question

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new contributor, so if its not the best help, sry but i am trying :)

have you tried a solution where you are using Math.toRadiants() in your g.rotate() function? in this video: [Java: Rotating and scaling images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHfGiTFWoc4)
 the image rotates without jumping, it's at 6:42 in the video.

So in your solution, it would look like that: `g.rotate(Math.toRadiants(r += 0.005));`

Comment: thank you for your attention, but i've already recieve correct answer from comments, i've mistaked with antialiasing hint..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).